# Continuity of convolution

Tags: continuity, convolution

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded function, $\phi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be in $C^\infty$. 
Is it true that $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x-t)f(t)$ is in $C^\infty$? And how to prove it if it's true?

Comment: You might want a compactly supported $\phi$ for this (not for regularity reasons but for $F$ to be defined).

Comment: @nicomezi if $\phi = \frac{a}{x^2 + a^2}$ for $a > 0$, will it be ok?

Comment: It might be useful to look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614941/continuity-of-parameter-dependent-integral-source-needed), and the linked page to parameter integrals [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Parameter-dependent_integral). Using the dominated convergence theorem will get you what you want.

Comment: Not it is not ok unless you add some hypothesis on $f$. For example if $f(x) =x ^2$, $F$ is not defined.