A problem in 47th page of Evans' Partial Differential Equations
As the red lines in picture below, first, I think the boundary
$$
\frac{1}{t^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/4t}
$$
on $\mathbb R^n \times [\delta, \infty)$  depends on $\delta$. Namely,
$$
0 \le \frac{1}{t^{n/2}} e^{-|x|^2/4t} \le C(\delta)
$$
So, what does the  uniformly bounded  means?
Besides,   how to get $u\in C^\infty (\mathbb R^n\times (0,\infty))$ ?  Some theorem seems to be used here, but the author doesn't say it.




Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem



Yes, the bound depends on $\delta$ since if you take $x=0$, you get $1/t^{n/2}$, which is not bounded.
To prove the regularity of $u$, fix $(x_0,t_0)$ with $t_0>0$ and take $\delta=t_0/2$. Then in the ball $B((x_0,t_0),\delta)$ you can apply the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to prove that $u$ and all its derivatives are continuous in the ball. By the arbitrariness of the point, you get the result.

Could you explain in detail how to apply the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem? I have included it in my problem, but I don't know  how to use it. Thank you.

Have you ever heard of the continuity of integrals depending on a parameter? Take a look at this link. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614941/continuity-of-parameter-dependent-integral-source-needed
